# I want to select two dates in this program, if I try to execute it is showing datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I want to select two dates in this program here, if I try to execute it is showing:

> datepicker is not a function

Code:

```
  var startDate;               
    $("#validFrom").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: true,
        closeOnDateSelect: false,
        closeOnTimeSelect: true,
        initTime: true,
        format: 'd-m-Y H:m',
        minDate: 0,
        roundTime: 'ceil',
        onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
            startDate = $("#validFrom").val();
        }
    });
    $("#validTill").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: true,
        closeOnDateSelect: false,
        closeOnTimeSelect: true,
        initTime: true,
        format: 'd-m-Y H:m',
        onClose: function (current_time, $input) {
            var endDate = $("#validTill").val();
            if (startDate > endDate) {
                alert('Please select correct date');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where's your html?

Comment: `datetimepicker()` is not a standard jQuery function. If you're getting that error it means you have not included the library which contains that function, or the path to it is incorrect.

Comment: Is the `datepicker` library added?

Comment: <input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="datepicker" name="from" id="validFrom" />
                            <input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="datepicker" name="till" id="validTill">

Comment: if you use bootstrap than add bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js and bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css in your index.html file

Comment: i'm using in microsoft visual studio i can't include library

Comment: here you use .datetimepicker({ so i think your error for datetimepicker not datepicker

Comment: libraries are already included in this project.... now i need two dates where end date sholud be greater than start date

Comment: without using any libraries how can i validate that

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect a library for use, something like that
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: without using datepicker can't we do validation for two dates